# Apache2 "Response header name '<!--' contains invalid characters, aborting request"

Tags: python, apache, http, cgi

**Edit**

The problem had nothing to do with the http header. It was a variable that was called in the cgi/python script before it was defined. Just in case others also try to work with an error message like that but can't find the reason for it.

---

I have inherited a website based on apache2/python/cgi scripts that I'm trying to maintain, but sometimes I'm struggling with really unhelpful errors. In this case, I get `The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.` when clicking on an element on a page. The error log gives me the following information:
`[Fri Jul 28 14:11:15.150877 2017] [http:error] [pid 1727] [client 193.174.111.250:53426] AH02429: Response header name '<!--' contains invalid characters, aborting request`

Based on a similar [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/853103/500-internal-server-ah02429-response-header-name), I'm assuming the error is quite new, but I can't find the problem. Especially since the link / the script name stays the same. It works when first opening the site, but then stops working when I click something which does not refer me to a different site/script. How can that be the header's fault?

Just in case, here is the code that generates the beginning of the web page:

```
Code = "Content-Type: text/html\n\n"
Code += "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN'>\n<html>\n"    
Code += "<head>\n  <title>BACTOME: RELATIVE EXPRESSIONS</title>\n"
...
```

As far as I understand now, the first line constitutes the only HTTP header I have. There is no `'<!--'` as stated in the error log. Does the header need anything else to be functional?

PS: Alternatively, if there's any easy way to turn these generic errors into more verbose ones, I'd also be very interested in that.

Comment: You seems to confuse **HTTP Headers** and **HTML's `<head>` tag**. So two solutions: 1. the code you pasted is _really_ how you generate http headers. If yes, this is really not what http headers should looks like. 2. This is not how you generate http headers, but html and so error happend somewhere else.

Comment: You are right, of course, that's the HTML header and not HTTP. I haven't found any code for that yet, so I didn't realise I was looking at the wrong thing...

Comment: If you are sure your question is not a _good question_ (aka not something which will efficiently helps others) it would be fair to delete it.

Comment: But I still don't know how to resolve the problem or where to find an answer... Is it really such a bad question? With no experience in this field, I really don't know.

Comment: If you can not provide helpful infos that make question answerable it's a bad question. Could you provide request's HTTP header?

Comment: Is that better?

Comment: If I get this error because there's a problem with the response header, that means a different response was generated before I got the 500 error, right? Is there any place where I can actually **see** this response? I would have liked to edit my question accordingly, but apparently I can't create new paragraphs. :-/

Comment: You can use `curl -I "http://www.urlofyourapp.com/foo/bar"`

Comment: Thanks! It only gives me the error response, like Chrome, though, and I can't find any response header with '<!--' like the error.log says.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The answers from @eorochena and @dogacan are special cases. In general:

*You get this error if an exception is raised in a Python CGI script.*

A good way of figuring out what went wrong is to invoke Python's CGI module debug helper function at the beginning of your CGI script like this:

`cgitb.enable(display=0, logdir=OUTDIR)`

where `OUTDIR` is a directory name. If your CGI scripts raises some exception, then Apache puts an HTML file into that directory. The file has some garbage name such as `tmpw4olz3xr.html`, and at its end it contains the Python stack trace enclosed within HTML comments (`<!--` ... `-->`). This is the information that will help you fix the problem.

Notes:

1. The `display=0` parameter means that the error details are not shown
   in the browser to your users.
2. You should probably comment out
   `cgitb.enable(...)` when you are sure your script works OK.

Comment: Thank you! The scripts I "inherited" all have their own debugging functions, but I'm definitely keeping this one in mind.

Comment: @Lilith-Elina Glad that I could help. If you like my answer, could you please upvote it? We all live from the market, you know... :-))) cheers, Laryx

Answer (score 3):

## Purpose

I think the purpose using cgitb is to get the whole information from web browser to help debugging.So we sholud correct the problem, not avoid the problem.

## Do some research

Let us have a look at the information:

```
AH02429: Response header name '<!--' contains invalid characters, aborting request
```

It indicates the header name contains invalid characters, so i do some research on cgitb.py code as follow:

```
    def reset():
    """Return a string that resets the CGI and browser to a known state."""
    return '''<!--: spam
Content-Type: text/html

<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> -->
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> --> -->
</font> </font> </font> </script> </object> </blockquote> </pre>
</table> </table> </table> </table> </table> </font> </font> </font>'''
```

This function returns the characters `<!--`. But apache httpd treat it as response header name which should not contain `<!--`.
There is also a open [issue8704](https://bugs.python.org/issue8704) in the Issue Tracker of python.

## Maybe not a good solution

I do not know the should we delete the code in cgitb.py or adjust the configration of apache httpd. My solution is deleting some code as follows:

```
        return '''
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> -->
<body bgcolor="#f0f0f8"><font color="#f0f0f8" size="-5"> --> -->
</font> </font> </font> </script> </object> </blockquote> </pre>
</table> </table> </table> </table> </table> </font> </font> </font>'''
```

Then it works very well, and it has good view.Anyone know what is the situation in ngix?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the way the aligment of the output from the print statement

Before:

```
try:
    if <some-condition>
        message = "%s" % filename
    else:
        message = "file not found"
    print """\n
        Content-Type: text/html\n
        <html><body>
        <p>%s</p>
        </body></html>
        """ % (message,)
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

After:

```
try:
    if <some-condition>:
        message = "%s" % filename
    else:
        message = "file not found"
    print """\
Content-Type: text/html\n
<html><body>
<p>%s</p>
</body></html>   
""" % (message,)
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: At the beginning? Interesting! That's missing in ALL of the scripts that generate this website. I'm currently on vacation but I'll definitely have a look at that once I'm back in the office. Thank you for sharing your insight! :-)

Comment: That is definitely not the problem. Adding a newline BEFORE the Content-Type results in only the code being printed instead of the website being displayed.

Comment: you are correct the issue is the alignment of the html text inside your print statement, check my edit answer

Comment: Good to know, thanks! In the scripts I have, there's only one line each, so no accidental indentation, but it's good to be aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

For the same error, in a similar printing case, it was due to database collation; changing it to a UTF-8 helped me.